# Adding a custom method as a key listener to a component

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to use a different approach to define separate methods as listeners for each component in my swing frame.

For the **action listener**, it's done as easy as defining a private void with this signature:

```
private void myButtonActionListener(ActionEvent e)
```

and assigning it to the button using a method reference operator:

```
myButton.addActionListener(this::myButtonActionListener);
```

however, it seems that it doesn't work for **key listeners**. I defined the method like this:

```
private void myTextBoxKeyPressed(KeyEvent event)
```

but this line of code raises an error saying that "*it's not a functional interface*":

```
myTextBox.addKeyListener(this::myTextBoxKeyPressed);
```

any ideas how to fix this problem as unlike an action listener, a key listener has more than one method to be implemented.

I'm well aware of other approaches like class implementing the listener or using an anonymous inner class, but I prefer to find a new way to keep my code cleaner.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AbstractAction, and either JComponent.setAction or Jcomponent.getActionMap()

```
public MyAction extends AbstractAction {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Java is smart enough to be able to treat a function `myButtonActionListener` with the appropriate declaration, as if you implemented an anonymous class that implements the required interface [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). That's the only reason `myButtonActionListener` can be used as you described, because ActionListener only requires you to implement one function and nothing else.

However, [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) requires *three (!)* functions to be implemented. Java has no way to understand which of these three functions you are trying to "implement", because their declaration is the same and even if it did, then you still didn't implement the other two which is illegal by design, because you cant tell if the function using your KeyListener uses them. You won't get around it. If an implementation of an interface is needed, then that's what you need to provide.

To maybe make it a little bit cleaner, you could create an object inline that implements your desired Interface. Here's an example using the Runnable Interface:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
};
```